# How to access a specific element of API data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API that returns data in JSON data. I am somewhat new to React and this was a pre-developed project that I am assigned. So I am not able to figure things out a bit.
In this code below the api stores the data to the obj appData which has some more elements which i want to show in console but somehow its not working how to do it?

```
componentDidMount(){

    Client.getAppData().then(res=>{

                this.setState({
                    initiated: true,
                    appData: res
                }); 

    })

    this.setState({
        // visibleSidebar: window.innerWidth > 720,
        innerWidth: window.innerWidth
    })
}

render(){
    const value = this.state.appData;
    console.log(value["OPERATING_CITIES"]);
```

In the last line I am getting the error. console.log(value) works well return the full json object.But I want a specific element. How to do it?

Comment: add the console output of `value`.

Comment: Add the API response

Comment: it returns this JSON:-

http://doorhopper.in/api/userAppData

Comment: can you try `console.log(typeof value)`?

Comment: The appData is set asynchronously and may have not been set while trying to console log in the render method. Either log the response in the then method of getAppData or in the render method with console.log(value && value["OPERATING_CITIES"]);

Comment: @GSSwain this works but how

Comment: What would be a correct way to access it then ? I mean I want to use if else on these object values on a later on stage..would you like to talk in messages?

Comment: @J.Doe I have added an answer on how you should go about it. You can reach me in case you have any doubts with this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `appData` is set `asynchronously` and may have not been set while you are trying to `log` in the `render` method. Either log the response in the `then` method of `getAppData` or in the `render` method with `console.log(value && value["OPERATING_CITIES"]);`

You can either set an empty object in your initial state

```
componentDidMount(){

Client.getAppData().then(res=>{
    this.setState({
        initiated: true,
        appData: res // This is where you are setting the data and this is asynchronous
    });
})

this.setState({
    // visibleSidebar: window.innerWidth > 720,
    innerWidth: window.innerWidth,
    appData: {} //Option 1: You can initialize here with an empty object and you don't have to add checks in your render method
})
```

}

Or you need to handle it in the `render` method

```
const value = this.state.appData;
if(value){ //Option 2: check if value has been set, default it was undefined
 // do your rendering 
} else {
 // You can display a loading spinner or something...
}
```